# Parcel Build Failed with error @parcel/resolver-default: Cannot load file '../../../../../css/main.css' in './src'

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, parceljs

I use parcel@2.7.0. Everytime I load any external css or javascript file in my index.html, Parcel always fail to build with error :

**Build failed.**

**@parcel/core: Failed to resolve './css/main.css' from './src/index.html'***

**@parcel/resolver-default: Cannot load file '../../../../../css/main.css' in './src'.**

Here is my Code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Parcel V2 Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

main.css

```
body{
    background: cyan;
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "parceltutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel src/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/resolver-glob": "^2.7.0",
    "parcel": "^2.7.0"
  }
}
```

I also install @parcel/resolver-glob and here's my .parcelrc configuration

```
{
    "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
    "resolvers": ["@parcel/resolver-glob", "..."]
}
```

I tried to remove my .parcel-cache just like what other people say or do, but it still throw me that error. Thank you

[Here's my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUaEs.png)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `.module.css`? Reference: https://parceljs.org/languages/css/

Comment: Alright, thanks for the solution krisnamic. However, those errors still appear. Somehow my project able to build and run if i put and run my project in my C Drive. Do you think code in D drive may cause some trouble? Is it better for me to put my project in C drive? Thanks anyway 

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).